# Transparent Shadow Shader Unity5

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, vuforia

I use the following shader in unity 4.6.2, but unfortunately it doesn't work in unity5. I have an object in an AR scene (vuforia 4) and I want to show the shadows on a plane which is under the object. That plane should be transparent and only show the shadows, like in the picture.

[image: Like in this picture here]

this is the shader which works in unity 4.6.2

```
Shader "TransparentShadowShader" {

Properties
{
    _ShadowColor ("Shadow Color", Color) = (0,0,0,1)
}

Category {

Blend  SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

Lighting Off
Zwrite Off
LOD 200


SubShader
{
    Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" }

    CGPROGRAM
    #pragma surface surf Custom

    struct Input {
        float2 pos : POSITION;
    };

    uniform float4 _ShadowColor;

    void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o)
    {
        //Pass through shadow colour to lighting model
        o.Albedo = _ShadowColor.rgb;
        o.Alpha  = _ShadowColor.a;
    }

    half4 LightingCustom(SurfaceOutput s, half3 lightDir, half3 viewDir, half atten)
    {
        half4 c;

        //Inverse illumination - atten accounts for shadowing
        c.rgb = s.Albedo.rgb * 1.0f-atten;
        c.a   = s.Alpha * 1.0f-atten;

        return c;
    }
    ENDCG
}
}

Fallback "VertexLit", 2

}
```

this is what I am getting in unity5, using this shader

[image]

Comment: Can you explain in what way the shader doesn't work?

Comment: I added a picture of the shader.. It looks like it is inverted or something.

Comment: @Jenny have you found a solution ?